# Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I had this error

```
Error:(45, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'LaTaxi2' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
<a href="fixGradleElements">Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project</a></li><li>The project 'LaTaxi2' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

`build.gradle` content

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
//        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        /* CHANGE to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'  for STABLE BUILD TOOL VERSION*/
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
//        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`build .gradle` module app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
//    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.techware.lataxi"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    /* Remove This to remove Crashlytics and Fabric */

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
/*    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }*/
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}







apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: For me, the issue was that I had put the implementation in my project's build.gradle instead of module app build.gradle. Once I changed it worked fine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To use the DSL `implementation()` you have to use:

- The updated gradle plugin for Android 3.0.0
- The gradle version 3.4 or later

Then in your `build.gradle` you have to use:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
    }
}
```

In your `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

More detailed [info here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html).

Comment: @MohammadAminMoordani this is some separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. There is something wrong with your build.gradle file. You may wish to consider asking a separate question,

Answer (score 35):

I had such a simple reason for this not working that I must post my answer to prevent anybody else going through this.

Don't put repositories and dependencies in the file called `build.gradle (Project: YourProjectName)`! There is a comment in that file that says:

```
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
```

Good job to whoever put that note in there. Instead, place your repositories and dependencies in the similarly named module file `build.gradle (Module: app)`.

There should already be a `dependencies` function. You may need to add repositories function. In my case, it was:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

This should let you sync and recognize `implementation`.

Comment: I _wish_ this had stopped me going through the same - I just spent most of today trying to work out what was wrong, including reinstalling Android Studio, fiddling with my settings, installing new SDKs etc. The problem for me was that the comment you mention is _inside_ the `buildscript` braces, so I thought it might be ok to put dependencies _outside_ the braces. To reiterate: MAKE SURE you put things in the `build.gradle` for your *app* or *module* - _not_ for the project.

Comment: This is exactly what I went through. It is worth noting that the SDK will suggest that you may need an update even though that was not the problem in our case.

Comment: Right.  I am coming to Android Studio from Visual Studio and AS is using "Project" like VS uses "Solution"; and AS is using "Module" like VS uses "Project" … at least this is what it seems to me.

Comment: This just saved me, had ignored the commented lines, until I found your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 24):

or if you don't want to update to the latest Gradle, go back to using DSL method `compile()` instead of `implementation()`

Comment: thanks a lot, your solution is quick and worked perfectly

Comment: compile() is expected to be deparacted by the end of 2018, so I wouldn't change it, and focus on fixing the error

Answer (score 21):

As a beginner, I discovered that there's 2 build.gradle files

It's worth checking that you didn't add the line in the wrong file.
I added mine in the project file whereas I should have added it in the module one.

[image: You can see here the 2 build in the android view]

Comment: This was the answer for me.

Answer (score 4):

You using Turkish workspace, 
below change solves the problem

```
testImplementation -> testİmplementation,
androidTestImplementation -> androidTestİmplementation
androidTestImplementation -> androidTestİmplementation
```

Answer (score 3):

`implementation()` has replaced `compile()` configuration, which will be DEPRECATED by the end of 2018.

In order to fix your errors and use it, you must update to **Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0** (or higher). As a result of this update, you also need to update Gradle to **Gradle 4.1** (or higher). You also need to use **Build Tools 26.0.2** (or higher), meaning to update your `buildToolsVersion` in your `build.gradle`, or just completely remove it from there (as, since 3.0.0, the minimum required version is used by default). You also need to update to **Android Studio 3** (or higher) in order to use those advanced versions.

You can read about the changelog of android gradle plugin 3.0.0, the improved compile times, and more, here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-0-0

**So how to update Android Gradle Plugin and Gradle?**

**OPTION 1: Manually**

In your `build.gradle` find your gradle classpath and update version to gradle 3.0. Also, google() maven's repository should be added:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

In gradle-wrapper.properties find your distributionUrl and update to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

**OPTION 2: Through project properties**
(But notice the manual configuration WILL override it)

Go to *File→Project Structure→Project*

[image]

One last thing, you can also choose whether to replace compile() by implementation() or by api(). By default I would suggest just to use implementation(). You can read more about the differences here: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was just a typo. It was an extra sign "/" after one of rows

Comment: @TaslimOseni it doesn't matter

Comment: My bad, I thought this was was a vague answer, didn't read through it properly.

Comment: Yes, the typo. "implmentation" instead of "implementation" in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar errors. when I tried to include the recyclerview dependencies from may build.gradle(Module: app) with a code like so.

```
//other build.gradle(Module: App) code above
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

So the simple way I fixed this is by changing the code to this, where I changed the implement to compile while retaining every other code and their version numbers.

```
//other build.gradle(Module: App) code above
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

I hope this helps some one having similar issues.
PS: The actual error was caused by `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'` and changing the code to `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'` got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i add these line and issue resolved

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```