# Error:(9, 0): 'google()' Gradle DSL method not found

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

hi after i slove my problem in this  question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838173/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-implementation/45838308?noredirect=1#comment78634287_45838308)

after building i receive this one

```
Error:This Gradle plugin requires Studio 3.0 minimum
```

then i update gradle-wrapper.properties to 3.3 
i receive this

```
Error:(9, 0): 'google()' Gradle DSL method not found
```

here is my build gradle file

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        /* CHANGE to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'  for STABLE BUILD TOOL VERSION*/
     //  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7'
     //   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // We recommend changing it to the latest version from our changelog:
        // https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
//        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is build gradle module app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
//    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.techware.lataxi"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    /* Remove This to remove Crashlytics and Fabric */

  /*  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }*/
/*    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:2.0.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }*/
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}







apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `google()` repo requires also [gradle v4](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html#google()) and Android Studio 3.x.

Try to use in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

In any case you can use the same maven repo using `{ url 'https://maven.google.com'}` (it is the same).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
 //
}
```

Comment: after doing them again Error:This Gradle plugin requires Studio 3.0 minimum

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 3.x ?

Comment: Then you have to use `maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }` instead of `google()`. It is the same.

Comment: look at my build.gradle i already do that ... but i get Error:This Gradle plugin requires Studio 3.0 minimum  should i update my android studio to 3?

Comment: In the top level file posted you have the google() repo in the buildscript block. Using Android studio 2.3 use the gradle plugin 2.3.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152684/discussion-between-mohammad-amin-moordani-and-gabriele-mariotti).

Comment: if i use gradle plugin 2.3.3 i get gradle dsl implemntion not found

Comment: I know it, but since you are trying to use functions in new beta plugin (3.0), I suggest you using also android studio 3.x (beta).

Comment: Thank you so much.Awesome ans its help me more.thank a lot. Mr.Gabriele Mariotti