# build gradle causes: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'

Tags: android, plugins, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

My android version is 2.3.3. I update android sdk (26). I get an error after updating. I'm having trouble with build.gradle. What's wrong my code? How to use the DSL implementation() ? How can I configure this project to run ?

build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'    
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}    
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}    
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'    
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ppl.restaurant"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.1"
    implementation 'info.androidhive:barcode-reader:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Error Message

```
Error:(38, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Restaurant' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
<a href="fixGradleElements">Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project</a></li><li>The project 'ABC' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Comment: set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3`

Comment: Yes, already set..

Comment: show your app level `build.gradle`

Comment: use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'` . Read https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: Go through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838173/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-implementation

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1. So, I Upgrade Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 ?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it this solutions, try this,

> **build.gradle (Project)** file **buildscript** and **allprojects** area

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

> **build.gradle (Module)** file **dependencies area**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the official doc, the [`implementation()`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations) DLS requires (currently)

- Gradle v.4
- Android Studio 3.x.
- Gradle plugin for Android 3.x

Try to use in `gradle-wrapper.properties` use:

```
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

As gradle plugin for Android use:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
```

More information about the [migration to plugin v3 here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html).

Comment: I don't want to use beta, I want to use stable 2.3.3. any way ?

Comment: @AprilMoe In this case you can use compile() as the other dependencies in your project. No way to use implementation() with 2.3.3.

Comment: I download Android Studio 3, beta 2, set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'` `distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip`.

Comment: Error `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-beta2) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-41
   is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:44 to override.`

Comment: @AprilMoe this is some separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. Just use the same version for all support libraries. You may wish to consider asking a separate question.

Comment: now I return to use android studio 2.3.3. `gradle:2.3.3` I don't want to use implementation(), now I want to use only compile in version 2.3.3. when I Rebuild, I show `Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Workspace/MyApplication/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>` I can't click `Install Repository and sync project` to update

Comment: @AprilMoe It is a different problem. Since 25.4.0 all support libraries are in google maven repo. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0-beta2. Add in your `repositories` block `maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }`.
Also currently you can use the stable 26.0.1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "compile" and android studio 2.3, use this:

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.28.0'

That work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved it like this:

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.28.0'

You need android studio 3.0 to use "implementation" but with android studio 2.3 work with "compile"

P.D.: Sorry my english.