# How to fix " ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'testImplementation()' "

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

**It solved!** I completely deleted Android Studio and gradle files. Then I reinstalled Android Studio and how I dont know but it solved.

---

I updated Android Studio to the latest version with IDE and plugins. But then this error came out.

I tried every answer I can see but even so these are not working for my problem. Here are some things I tried:

- Change the testImplementation to testİmplementation...
- Change the gradle versions (from Project Structure or as manual)
- Update lastest gradle version (5.5)
- ...

`build.gradle` (content)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`build.gradle` (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.basayproductions.myapplication11"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Here is the error message, that in my Build console (I tried the suggestions):

```
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'testImplementation()'
Possible causes:
The project 'My Application11' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.1 and sync project

The project 'My Application11' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838173/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-implementation)