# ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implemantation()' Possible causes

Tags: javascript, android

> ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implemantation()' Possible
>   causes: The project 'myproject' may be using a version of the Android
>   Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile'
>   was added in 1.1.0).

Using gradle latest version.

Comment: There is a typo in implemantation(). Use implementation

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you correctly spell `implementation` like so:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

Other than that (if the problem persists after fixing the typo) this question has an answer here:

[Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838173/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-implementation)

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.Gradle


//noinspection GradleDependency
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.neurondigital.cityguide"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            //useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true

            //useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'


    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:5.0.13.0@aar'//do not upgrade this library
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:2.0.46.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.1.1'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-views:3.1.0"


    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.0'
   // implementation 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'com.github.frank-zhu:pullzoomview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:3.0.8'
    implementation 'com.truizlop.sectionedrecyclerview:library:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.13.0'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:5.0.0' // Facebook Core only (Analytics)
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
mantation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'



}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```